# Turtlebot2 power for laptop

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I would like to use the battery of the Kobuki base of my turtlebot to give power to the laptop. I would like the laptop to take power from the Kobuki only when the Kobuki base is on the loading station. For that I need to activate or not the external power for the Kobuki.
I found a function "Command Command::SetExternalPower(const DigitalOutput &digital_output, Command::Data &current_data)" in the file kobuki_driver/src/driver/command.cpp. And if I am right, this function allows us to activate or not the external power of the Kobuki. But I don't know how to use this function. Is there any documentation somewhere ? or examples ?
Or should I use another function ?

Thanks for help.
Caroline

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58247/turtlebot2-power-for-laptop/) by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 395 on 2013-03-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The 19V laptop power port passes through from the charging dock or power port any time the Kobuki is docked or plugged in.  There's no need for software.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3